# Using Drip with CounterClockwise (Clojure in Eclipse)

Tags: eclipse, clojure, counterclockwise

Is it possible to use [Drip](https://github.com/flatland/drip) for [Clojure](https://github.com/flatland/drip/wiki/Clojure) with Eclipse/[CounterClockwise](http://code.google.com/p/counterclockwise/), and assuming it is, how do you go about setting it up?